# It's necessary to synchronize the use of the global variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I've got this code, here need to sync the use of the global variable c ?
Is it feasible that the streams will start work at the same time and one thread will overwrite the result of another thread and eventually get either 2 or 7?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int c = 0;

void* write(void*)
{
    c += 2;
}

void* read(void*)
{
    c += 7; 
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;

    std::cout << "first C = " << c << std::endl;
    int r1 = pthread_create(&t1, 0, &write, 0);
    int r2 = pthread_create(&t2, 0, &read, 0);
    pthread_join(t1, 0);
    pthread_join(t2, 0);
    std::cout << " C = " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with mutexes and locking? Edit: This is a classic readers-writers problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Comment: Yes I am familiar with mutexes, thanks for the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to protect the access to the global variable. You either need to use a [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) or you need to use an [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) type (including atomit operations to modify them).

If you don't do this, the problem is that a normal `+=` requires a read operation, adds some value and then writes the result back into memory. If two threads do this at the same time, they can overlap, for example both will read `0` in your example code, then both write their result which mean that the last write operation wins and hence the other addition is lost. You end up with `2` or `7` instead of `9` as you already suspected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple threads accessing an object possibly simultaneously and, at least, one of these threads changes the object, you have a data race unless the access to the object is synchronized. If you have a data race, the behavior of the program is undefined.

That is, yes, you need to access `c` using appropriate synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

In SMP machines (with separate data cache memories), there is another subtle thing to consider, which is inter-thread memory synchronization. If the threads are running in different cores/CPUs, even if the two threads updating `c` do not run exactly the same time, they might not see the memory update from another thread immediately. For example using `pthread_mutex_t` to synchronize will take care of this problem.

Note that `pthread_join()` synchronizes memory with other threads so additional measures are not needed after joining your threads to guarantee `c` is seen with its updated value.

Here is the list of POSIX thread functions that are guaranteed to provide memory synchronization with other threads: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11.